# Avalonia - Updating ObservableCollection bound to DataGrid Items only displays the first item in DataGrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, avalonia

I am trying to learn Avalonia and I am using the FluentAvalonia NuGet package which exposes some WinUI controls into Avalonia, a DataGrid among others.

I have a DataGrid with the `Items` property bound to an `ObservableCollectionExtended` property.

My DataGrid is as follows:

```xml
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Items="{Binding SystemInfoEntries}"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                  CanUserSortColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Value}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The `SystemInfoEntries` is an `ObservableCollectionExtended` property which is defined as follows:

```cs
private IObservableCollection<SystemInfoEntry> _systemInfoEntries;

public IObservableCollection<SystemInfoEntry> SystemInfoEntries
{
    get => _systemInfoEntries;
    set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _systemInfoEntries, value);
}
```

The `SystemInfoEntry` model contains just two properties `Name` and `Value`, both are strings:

```cs
public class SystemInfoEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _value;
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get => _name;
        set => SetField(ref _name, value);
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set => SetField(ref _value, value);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected bool SetField<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value)) return false;
        field = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is the following:

When I construct the ViewModel, I initialize the observable collection with a placeholder item like this:

```cs
SystemInfoEntries = new ObservableCollectionExtended<SystemInfoEntry>()
{
    new()
    {
        Name = "Select a site",
        Value = "Select a site"
    }
};
```

This placeholder item is rendered perfectly in the DataGrid. However, if I later clear the observable collection and populate it with more items, only the first item of the new collection is displayed.

For example, this code below will make the DataGrid display only one row with "Property 0" and "Value 0" in its 2 columns.

```cs
SystemInfoEntries.Clear();

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    SystemInfoEntries.Add(new() { Name = $"Property {x}", Value = $"Value {x}" });
}
```

What is the issue here? What am I missing? If I populate the DataGrid without the placeholder items, it populates fine. It seems to be working incorrectly when the Observable Collection is already filled with items and I clear those items to add new ones. The first time it works, subsequent changes to the list make the DataGrid display only the first item in that list.

Any thoughts are highly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` from DataGrid configuration

With `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` run your app, and try to scroll by mouse wheel on DataGrid. You will see a scroll bar, and items.

It's happening because, at your first initialization

```
SystemInfoEntries = new ObservableCollectionExtended<SystemInfoEntry>()
{
    new()
    {
        Name = "Select a site",
        Value = "Select a site"
    }
};
```

DataGrid automatically allocate space for it, but when you reinitialize, your DataGrid size is minimal, and it's use automatically mode `VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` and take minimal size, but you can see all items by scrolling.